# Safely Cancel a MySQL import

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to upload a large database:

$mysql -u USERNAME -p MY_DATABASE < MY_DATABASE.sql

But the process is going extremely slowly, I would like to cancel and try again with different settings. How can I cancel this upload 'safely'? Or what is the best way to clean up my database after forced termination of the import?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can kill MySQL process involved in your `MY_DATABASE.sql`

This show you running processes:

```
show processlist;
```

Then you should kill the process selecting it by the correct `process_id` from the user and time shown from previous command to understand which one is the correct one, if others processes are running:

```
kill process_id
```

I think that cleaning the DB is the hardest work, because it depends on the `MY_DATABASE.sql` content: if it populates a table, you can simply truncate it, if it create a DB and upload tables, views, stored procedures and other elements, you should drop the DB.

If you take a look at the `MY_DATABASE.sql` content and at the server content after killing the process (db created? tables or other elements created?) you will understand what to do.

If, as I can imagine, the script creates entirely a DB, you should only have to drop the DB created from the previous interrupted upload, if any, and restart the upload.

Answer (score 1):

Rather stopping MySQL import with killing the process, I prefer use terminate key which is `ctrl+c` and `service mysqld restart` or `service mysql restart`.

This just ends the import process and it gets sometimes to end. Once it's done you can go with your process. If you end the process with killing it may cause some unexpected errors like a mysql server crash.